# How to fix replaced letter showing as '{' instead of 'a' which is what its meant to show

Tags: python, grok

I am working on a competition at school called Grok. Which is a Python competition. I want to replace the letter 'z' with 'a' in the char loop. But when I put in a word with the letter z in it, the letter appears as { instead of a.

```
text = input('Word? ')


for char in text:
  if 'z' in char:
    new_char = chr(ord(char) + 1)
    new_char.replace('z', 'a')
  else:
    new_char = chr(ord(char) + 1)


  print(new_char, end='')
```

If i put in a word like Pizza, the letters of z replace to { instead of a, like pi{{a, when I want it to produce Piaaa

Comment: `chr(ord('z') + 1)` returns `{` character . [That's why](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif).

Comment: `{` is the next Unicode character after `z`, so it is right behavior. You should consider using only the `replace`.

Comment: Note that this is essentially homework, and https://groklearning.com/ provides online tutor assistance within the system to help you figure it out for yourself, so you should really ask there rather than getting a solution here and learning little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help, I edited the code a bit using your answers and this seemed to work for me:

```
  text = input('Word? ')

# This loop will encrypt one letter at a time.
for char in text:
  # Encrypt char here!
  if 'z' in char:
    new_char = char.replace('z', 'a')
  else:
    new_char = chr(ord(char) + 1)


  # Print the new encrypted letter.
  print(new_char, end='')
```

Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

What about avoiding loops and just using `str.replace`:

```
text = text.replace('z', 'a')
```

Which will replace all occurrences of `'z'` with `'a'` in `text`.

Answer (score 0):

I think something wrong with

```
new_char = chr(ord(char) + 1)
```

Try print new_char after that line, and you will be known.

```
for char in text:
  if 'z' in char:
    new_char = chr(ord(char) + 1)
    print(new_char)
    new_char.replace('z', 'a')
  else:
    new_char = chr(ord(char) + 1)


  print(new_char, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `ord('z')` is 122 and `ord('{')` is 123. Something like

```
new_char = char(ord('a') + (ord(char) - ord('a') + 1) % 26)
```

should work.